# How to publish the same report to lots of different spots on my SSRS 2008 R2 server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, publish

I have SSRS 2008 R2 server that we use with our TFS 2010 projects.

Each project has more or less the same reports in it.  I have made a change to one of those reports.  Now I have two choices:

1. Go to each project and manually upload the changed report
2. Figure out a way to upload the changed report to all the folders at once.

Clearly I would prefer #2 (as I can see reports changing in the future.

Does anyone know a way to do this that does not use VB?  (I have a hard time reading VB and an even harder time adapting it to what I need and an even harder time debugging it.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like powershell a bit more than VB.net or C#.net?

http://www.powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=2045&categoryID=54

Powershell is very a handy thing to know if you are on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SSRS scripting tool like this one

Download: http://www.sqldbatips.com/samples/code/RSScripter/RSScripter.zip
Instructions: http://www.sqldbatips.com/samples/code/RSScripter/readme.htm

It has both a GUI tool as well as a command line utility and I can verify that it works well on SQL 2008 R2 servers.